# A package marked as automatic refuses to be removed by `apt autoremove` even though it is not required by anything

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I installed postgresql-11 on a pretty fresh install of Debian, and removed it with `apt purge postgresql-11` soon after. I did `apt autoremove` and found that 3 packets starting with postgresql were left.

I focused on postgresql-client-11 and checked `aptitude why postgresql-client-11`.

```
i   rsyslog           Suggests   rsyslog-mysql | rsyslog-pgsql
p   rsyslog-pgsql     Recommends postgresql-client
p   postgresql-client Depends    postgresql-client-11
```

Postgresql-client-11 is a dependency of a removed package... I also checked the 14673 lines long verbose output and the regex `/i \+[a-z0-9-]\+ \+\(Depends\|Recommends\|Suggests\|Provides\) \+postgresql-client-11` doesn't give me a single result (the regex works if I replace the first i character with p in case you think I messed up somehow).

If I do `apt rdepends postgresql-client-11`, it gives me:

```
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: postgresql-11
  Depends: postgresql-client
  Depends: postgresql-11
  Depends: postgresql-client
```

(Why the same result twice btw?)

Postgresql-11 is what I purged and postgresql-client is not installed as well. The result matches what I found in the verbose output of `aptitude why`.
A quick `apt list postgresql* --installed` gives me:

```
postgresql-client-11/stable,now 11.12-0+deb10u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
postgresql-client-common/stable,now 200+deb10u4 all [installed,automatic]
postgresql-common/stable,now 200+deb10u4 all [installed,automatic]
```

which are the three packages I wonder why they were not removed through `apt autoremove`.

Why is this package refusing to die when I do `apt autoremove`?

Comment: Does `apt autoremove` refuse to uninstall them or ignore them? (that command's output is missing)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: Does `apt -oApt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false` remove the packages?

Comment: @StephenKitt No, it doesn't, see > https://pastebin.com/E8pkis1x